# Proving whether or not $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(2i+2)=n^2+3n+2$

Tags: calculus, summation, solution-verification

I want to prove $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(2i+2)=n^2+3n+2$ by induction.

So if $p(k)$ is true, then $p(k+1)$ must also be true. At $k+1$ the sum should be $(k+1)^2+3(k+1)+2$ which is $k^2+2k+1+3k+3+2$ which is finally $k^2+5k+6$.

Okay so now if $p(k+1)$ is true, then the sum should be $k^2+5k+6$

Now when I do
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^m(2i+2)+\color{red}{(2m+2)}&=m^2+3m+2+\color{red}{(2m+2)} \\ \sum_{i=0}^{m+1}(2i+2)&=m^2+5m+4
\end{align*}
replacing $m$ with $k$, $$k^2+5k+4$$

But $k^2+5k+4\ne k^2+5k+6$, therefore by induction the proposition should be false

However, I'm reading online that it's true. What part of my work did I mess up on? Because I'm very confused where things went wrong. Everything seems reasonable.

Comment: You need to demonstrate that $p(k) \implies p(k+1)$, in this case you assume it to be true.

Comment: @Anacardium The result is true. For $n=1$, we have $1^2+3(1)+2= 6$ and the sum giving $(2(0)+2)+(2(1)+2)= 2+2+2= 6$.

Comment: Your mistake is what's in red.  You need to add $2(m+1)+2$ to each side because you're working with $P(m+1)$.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life I thought it was $$\left ( \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} 2i \right ) + 2$$ because of bad editing.

Comment: **Alternatively:** Your summing an **arithmettic progression** — the difference between successive terms is $[2(i+1)+2]-[2i+2]=2$. The sum of an arithmetic progression is given by the formula sum = (number of terms) $\times$ (first + last)/2, in this case $$(n+1)(2+2n+2)/2=(n+1)(n+2)=n^2+3n+2.$$

Comment: Whoever edited the red text to make it black -- not cool.  It should be restored to red, as that was the original poster's intent.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you for letting me know someone removed the colors. I fixed it. I'm guessing they changed the colors because the changes they wanted to make weren't enough characters.

Comment: Direct Proof is easier

Comment: @SteveMorris Feel free to show how a direct proof for this would work. I've only done direct proofs for simple things like showing $n^2$ is odd if $n$ is odd. Haven't done much else direct proofs

Comment: @Lex_i Two Hints. 1. What is the sum of first $n$ positive integers. 2. $ \sum_{i = 0}^{n} (a_i + b_i) =  \sum_{i = 0}^{n}a_i +  \sum_{i = 0}^{n} b_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.  You've made a minor mistake, which is the step in red.  When you add the next term necessary for $P(m+1)$, that means you need to add $2(m+1)+2$ to both sides, not $2m+2$.  Fix that and you'll see that the proof works.

Comment: I see. In my textbook the sum of integers $i$ up to $l$ was proved using the least element axiom, and when I saw $l$ being added to both sides I assumed it was just changing $i$ to $l$, but I realize now the author meant to add the value that comes from plugging in the new upper limit. 

Yikes, this is the kind of logic I used in my first discrete/structures midterm, I hope my professor is lenient with the grading.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you find an answer useful, upvotes and acceptances are always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For induction, imagine dominoes. You set one up and knock it over and the others fall.

First, to prove the statement by induction you need to prove a base case. [This is the first domino - the others can't fall if you don't knock one down to begin with!] So try proving the statement if $n=0,1,2$ to get a feel for things. [Only $n=0$ is really needed.]

Now you need to assume $n=k$ is true and prove it for $n=k+1$. Your issue is that you have done that but added a term that would not correspond to the $k+1$ term of the series:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} (2i+2)= \big(2(k+1) + 2\big) + \sum_{i=0}^k (2i+2)
$$
Hopefully, you should be able to fix things from there. [Look at the work, very little modification is necessary.]